# What is the value of $\Sigma \frac{1}{pqr}$ with $\frac{1}{a}>\frac{1}{pqr}$?

Tags: number-theory

What is the value of  $\Sigma \dfrac{1}{pqr}$ with $\dfrac{1}{a}>\dfrac{1}{pqr}>\dfrac{1}{z^3}$ where $a$ is a positive integer , $z$ is a positive prime larger than $a$ and the sum is over all primes $p,q,r$ smaller than $z$.

Comment: Do you really mean "all primes p,q,r smaller than q"? If so, you are summing over the empty set (since q cannot be smaller than itself) and the sum is thus 0 ;-)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler edited. thanks.

Comment: We can easily get a lower bound by taking $pq = a + o(ln(a))$ and then we arrive at a lower bound of $ln(ln(z^3/a))$ by Mertens theorem for the sum of reciprocal primes.

Comment: Likewise we can improve by considering $p = a + o(ln(a))$ and thus arrive at $2 ln(ln(\sqrt {z^3/a}))$.
Together with the other lower bound estimate we get a total lower bound estimate of $ln(ln(z^3/a)) + 2 ln(ln(\sqrt {z^3/a}))$. It seems an integral over $a$ or such would give a good estimate.

Comment: Btw the following integral might thus be usefull - if my guess is more or less correct - :
 $ \int ln(ln(z/x)) dx ==
-(z Ei(-Log(z/x))) + x ln(ln((z/x))) $